# Query secret value (password) from a JSON string

Tags: json, bash, jenkins, command-line-interface, aws-secrets-manager

I need to query the secret value from AWS Secrets Manager within Jenkins:

This is part of the pipeline:

```
sec=$(aws secretsmanager get-secret-value \
   --secret-id mySecretId \
   --query 'SecretString' \
   --output text)


echo "${sec}"

# Result: {"username":"gwuser","password":"myPasswordValue","dbInstanceIdentifier":"mySecretId"}
```

How can I now extract the "myPasswordValue"?

Comment: At this point you have a JSON string in a shell script variable. It's no longer an AWS question. You just need to use something like `jq` to parse out the value you need from the JSON string https://stedolan.github.io/jq/

Comment: Have you tried `--query 'SecretString.password'` ?

Comment: @Philippe Yes, it returns "None"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The suggestion by @Mark B works:

```
#!/bin/bash

sec=$(aws secretsmanager get-secret-value \
   --secret-id mySecretId \
   --query 'SecretString' \
   --output text | jq .password | tr -d '"')


echo "${sec}"

# Result: myPasswordValue
```

`tr -d '"'` removes the quotes.